# Setting clipboard data crashes program C win32

Tags: c, clipboard, winsock

I try to spam my client computer's clipboard with a string. It works when my server/client runs on the same machine. But when I move the client program to another machine it just crashes without any error code. How can I spam the clipboard of my client without my client program crashing everytime?

Server:

```
while (1)
{
    HANDLE buf = malloc(1048);
    r = recv(s, (char*)buf, 1048, 0);
    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("error receiving clipboard data\n");
        goto jumpThree;
    }
    printf("%s\n", (char*)buf);
    if (strncmp((char*)buf, "test", 4) == 0)// if we got the respond we expected
    {
        break;
    }
    free(buf);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Client:

```
while (1)
{
               const wchar_t* strData = L"I am spamming you";

                if (OpenClipboard(0)) {
                        
                HANDLE h = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
                        
                if (strncmp((char*)h, "test", 4) == 0)
                {
                    printf("TEST: %s\n", (char*)h);
                    int r = send(ClientSocket, (char*)h, 75, 0);
                    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        printf("error sending clipboard data\n");
                        goto jumpThree;
                    }
                    CloseClipboard();
                }
                        
        HGLOBAL hClipboardData;
        hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, sizeof(WCHAR) * (wcslen(strData) + 1));
        WCHAR* pchData;
        pchData = (WCHAR*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
        wcscpy(pchData, strData);
        GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
        SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hClipboardData);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

In the documentation it says that `SetClipboardData()` crashes when you call `EmptyClipboard()` with `OpenClipboard()` with `NULL` parameter. But I don’t call `EmptyClipboard()` so I don’t think that’s the problem.

Edit: I figured out it's because of the if else staments. I'm now looking for a fix.

Comment: On the server: `malloc()` returns a `void*` not a `HANDLE`. You  are not checking the pointer for NULL on failure. You are leaking the memory when the loop breaks. You are not checking the return value of `recv()` for 0 (peer disconnected). The received data received is not null terminated, or even guaranteed to hold a complete string.

Comment: On the client: you are not checking `GetClipboardData()` for NULL. You are not taking the text's actual length into account when sending it. `GetClipboardData()` returns a handle to a movable memory block, so you need to `GlobalLock()` it before typecasting it to access its content.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew that I had to check if `GetClipboardData()` returned `NULL`. Because if it returns `NULL`, the program crashes when trying to do some operation on the string like on this line: `if (strncmp((char*)h, "test", 4) == 0)`. So I added this code to my client program:

```
HANDLE h = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
if (h == NULL)
{
    printf("h is null\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    /* Do something here. Like go try GetClipboardData() again */
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: "*I didn't knew that I had to check if GetClipboardData() returned NULL*" - You would have if you had read its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata).